# Remove Grails Plugins and Dependencies

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Is there any Grails tip to figure out what dependencies / plugins my project is not using at runtime?  I want to start tidying up an existing project and one obvious thing is to tidy up the BuildConfig.groovy?

Thanks

Comment: This seems a tuff one

Answer (score 0):

You can use "grails dependency-report" command
https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html